# Can I migrate tables without the triggers?

Tags: oracle, sql-server-migration-assi

I'd like to migrate all tables, data, and indexes for a given Oracle schema (approx 2000 tables).

I do want to migrate the triggers. I am looking for a way to do this without visiting each table and deselecting its triggers.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer would be to migrate everything and build a script using something like;

```
select 'drop trigger ' || trigger_name || ';' from all_triggers where owner = 'MYSCHEMA';
```

Answer (score 0):

If your database is [11g](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Database#Releases_and_versions) or above, you can use the expdp utility with include=triggers qualifier.